# nodejs get all users and return users only name, id, image not all data

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb

i want to get all users name, profile picture, id but find() returns all data of that users like password, address etc. but i only want name, id, profile picture.this is my code

```
User.find()
.then(data => {

if (data==0) {
  res.status(500).send({
      message:"There are no user"
  });
}else{
  res.status(200).send( data );
}
  
})
  .catch(err => {
res.status(500).send({
  message:
    err.message || "Some error occurred while retrieving tutorials."
});
});
```

Comment: you could create a DTO (data transfer object) which references to the object by same id you defined in your user.service but only holds the parameters which you want to get. for example like this:
// //  export class User { id: string, username: string, password: string, moreInfo: string }    // // export class UserDto { id: string, username: string, moreInfo: string }. Then you create 2 service functions which get a dto and one that gets the whole user if needed

Comment: thank you for your answer. but i got another solution https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-select using this i can select particular fields like this User.find().select('name _id image').

Answer (score 0):

I'm hoping you're using mongoose for the same.

```
User.find({}, 'firstName lastName picture', function(error, data) {
if (error) {
    return res.status(500).send({
        msg: 'Error while finding records',
        data: []
    })
} else {
    return res.send(200).send({
            msg: 'recods found',
            data: data
        })
  }
```

});